# L2TP/IPSec Conectivity Problems

Tags: windows-7, vpn, openswan, debian-wheezy

We ar traying to establish a VPN to our office.
We sucesful configured a debian server using openswan and lx2tpd.
We test the conection on the local network, and established a VPN conection with the server.

The problem is, outside the office, I connect to the VPN over my iPhone, i have no connectivity, and i can only acces to the VPN Server. But the really important problem, is that on a laptop we could not establish a connection to the VPN. It's really strange.

We connect to the server using a public IP, with ports 500 and 4500 redirected to a local server in the network, on a virtualized machine.

Any idea how we could resolve this isue ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Check with tcpdump on the LAN interface whether the Debian server routes the VPN traffic to the LAN. If it does then
2. check whether the Debian server is the gateway for the LAN or whether the seperate gateway knows about the VPN address range and routes it to the Debian server. If that works
3. check whether the LAN systems have firewall settings which prevent access from the VPN address range (probably from everywhere except the LAN scope).